# Add optionnal parameters in my URL with Angular routing

Tags: angularjs, http, routes

Here is my link:

```
http://www.example.com/book/details:id/:type
```

Where "id" and "type" are custom variables. (i know how to build the link there is no problem with that)
And I want the "type" parameter to be optionnal, i've seen some example on the internet like "id:42?/:type" but that doesnt work...

Also my routing is handeling my link this way:

```
.when('/book/detail:id/:type', {templateUrl : 'partials/detailBook.html'})
```

Then I use AngularJS's $routeParamaters to get the parameters like in any other of my links.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: change to this `when('/book/detail/:id/:type?', {templateUrl : 'partials/detailBook.html'})`

Comment: this makes the type as optional parameter.

Comment: @Sravan Thanks, i will give it a try :)

Comment: @Sravan, worked like a charm, Thank sooo much :)! I may look a bit stupid for not trying this one, that just didnt maked sense for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should have `:type?` to make type as optional.

```
`when('/book/detail/:id/:type?', {templateUrl : 'partials/detailBook.html'})`
```

The confuguration can be something like,

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
     `when('/book/detail/:id/:type?', {templateUrl : 'partials/detailBook.html'})`
}]);
```

Comment: Will accept it when the protection time will be over ^^ Hope it will help other people out there!

Comment: didn't get you, protection time mean?

Comment: You can accept an answer only after a few minutes :) (i mean you can't accept it 2 seconds after it has been posted)